# Java create model with generic base model

Tags: java, oop

I want to create some classes that have almost the same attributes for each. Example:
1. Class A, attributes: String a, String b, String c, AnObject d
2. Class B, attributes: String a, String b, String c, OtherObject d

The difference between class A and B only in attributes d.

I have create a class

```
public class C <T> {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
    private T d;
}
```

Then, for class A

```
public class A extends C<A> {
    private SomeObject z;
}
```

And for class B

```
public class B extends C<B> {
    private OtherObject z;
    private Integer y;
}
```

However, it become a problem when I make it as JSON using jackson. `A` become something like this:

```
{
    "a": "",
    "b": "",
    "c": "",
    "d": {
        "a": null,
        "b": null,
        "c": null,
        "z": ""
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
{
    "a": "",
    "b": "",
    "c": "",
    "d": {
        "z": ""
    }
}
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two possible solutions here: using only generic class without inheritance or using inheritance without generics.

Classes `A` and `B` don't have to extend the class `C`. Those redundant properties get into JSON representation from the parent class (namely `C`).

```java
    public class C <T> {
        private String a;
        private String b;
        private String c;
        private T d;
    }

    public class A {
        private SomeObject z;
    }

    public class B {
        private OtherObject z;
        private Integer y;
    }

    // example of usage
    C<A> a = new C<>();
    a.setD(new A());
    // and so on
    C<B> b = new C<>();
    b.setD(new B());
    // and so on
```

The other way is to make `A` and `B` children of `C` which in this case doesn't have to be generic.

```java
    @JsonTypeInfo(
      use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
      include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, 
      property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({ 
      @Type(value = A.class, name = "a"), 
      @Type(value = B.class, name = "b") 
    })
    public class C {
        private String a;
        private String b;
        private String c;
    }

    public class A extends C {
        private SomeObject z;
    }

    public class B extends C {
        private OtherObject z;
        private Integer y;
    }

    // example of usage
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely happening because the way you are using Generics. Class C contains its child (private T d), so when you instantiated A, you inherit fields a, b, c and another instance of A, which will also contains fields a, b, c. Not sure what you're going for here but if you want to fix this remove the Generics (private T d) from c.

```
public class C {
    private String a;
    private String b;
    private String c;
}
public class A extends C {
    private SomeObject z;
}
```